# Terraform list object in Golang

Tags: go, terraform, terratest

I am trying to represent Terraform list of `objects` in Go i.e.

```
variable "map_roles" {
  description = "Additional IAM roles to add to the aws-auth configmap."
  type = list(object({
    rolearn  = string
    username = string
    groups   = list(string)
  }))
```

Are `rolearn` and others basic types or composite ones e.g. a map? And so is map_roles just a struct of strings and slice of string (list), or is it a struct of maps?

Comment: This isn't Go syntax, what exactly are you doing?

Comment: It's terraform syntax. I'm trying to represent that in Go

Comment: That depends on what level of abstraction you're using. Can you provide an example of what you're trying to write?

Comment: I'm using terratest (https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest) to test a terraform module (eks cluster). One of the input_variables I need to provide is `map_roles`

Comment: Terraform syntax is HCL, and it's already implemented in go https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl

Comment: Someone who knows terratest may be able to chime in, but I'm guessing it is just using combinations of `[]interface{}` and `map[string]interface{}` to hold the variable data.

Answer (score 1):

Terratest converts variable values given in `terraform.Options` to `-var` command line arguments using its internal function [`toHclString`](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/87e3c116f24bf0ec99c528debd849c6fb0fb74ba/modules/terraform/format.go#L101).

From reading through the implementation of that function and the other functions it calls, it seems like it will convert a Go `[]interface{}` value into Terraform tuple syntax and a Go `map[string]interface{}` into Terraform object syntax, so a valid value for the type constraint shown might look like this:

```golang
[]interface{}{
    map[string]interface{}{
        "rolearn":  "foo",
        "username": "bar",
        "groups":   []interface{"baz"},
    },
    map[string]interface{}{
        "rolearn":  "boop",
        "username": "beep",
        "groups":   []interface{"blurp"},
    },
}
```

Based on my read of the code (note: I didn't actually test it ) I would expect that to generate a `-var` argument value like this:

```
-var map_roles='[{"rolearn" = "foo", "username" = "bar", "groups" = ["baz"]},{"rolearn" = "boop", "username" = "beep", "groups" = ["blurp"]}]'
```